# Login verification Meteor

Tags: security, meteor, user-input

I want to create a verification process in my application (using Meteor)

I have these packages installed:

```
standard-app-packages
accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-blaze
bootstrap-3
accounts-password
iron-router
iron-router-progress
collection2
email
```

I have set the process.env.MAIL_URL (just using my gmail account for now)

I have set the Accounts.config:

```
Accounts.config({sendVerificationEmail: true, forbidClientAccountCreation: false});
```

When I set the forbidClientAccountCreation to true, I get the error message "Signups Forbidden" in my accounts-ui package.

However, when I set it to false, the user is created and then the verification email is sent, which kind of makes the whole process redundant.

Any hints on what I can do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in server code, create the user: https://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser

```
var userId = Accounts.createUser({email: "emailaddr"})
```

then send the enrollment and or verify email: https://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_sendenrollmentemail

```
Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId, [email])
```